# How to fix "bad string" error in json?

Tags: json

jsonlint.com throws the following error on my second line of code: "SyntaxError: Bad string on line 2"

But no matter what string I replace my current one with, it keeps throwing that error. Is it referring to something else other than "1"?

```
{
  "1": [{
    "city": "Paris",
    "country": "France",
    "date": 2015,
    "sights": [{"Eiffel Tower", "Versailles"}]
  }],
  "2": [{
    "city": "Rome",
    "country": "Italy",
    "date": 2016,
    "sights": [{"Parthenon"}]
  }]
}
```

Comment: Debug this by removing things one at a time, and see if the error goes away. The last thing you remove will be what caused the error. BTW, when I run this through JSONLint it says the error is on line 7, not line 2, around the `Eiffel Tower` part, noting that it expected a `:` and got `,` instead. That should be a good clue as to where the problem lies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your dates are wrong (they should be in quotes), and you have some unnecessary brackets going on. [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) can help you. Here is the valid JSON:

```
{
    "1": {
        "city": "Paris",
        "country": "France",
        "date": "2015-12-05",
        "sights": [
            "Eiffel Tower",
            "Versailles"
        ]
    },
    "2": {
        "city": "Rome",
        "country": "Italy",
        "date": "2016-11-07",
        "sights": [
            "Parthenon"
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Some of this is nonsense:

> Your dates are wrong (they should be in quotes)

The date you had is a perfectly valid one, it's just a year stored as a number. Why expand beyond the example given?

The main reason this didn't work is because of this `{"Eiffel Tower", "Versailles"}` - you defined an array with object syntax, rather than as `["Eiffel Tower","Versailles"]`.